# My geojson-file doesn't get loaded via fetch

Tags: leaflet, geojson, fetch-api

I am trying to load a geojson-file into my map via fetch right here
https://olive-highfalutin-crown.glitch.me/
but I get nothing shown to be loaded in my network sources.
That is my code therefore:

```
    fetch("https://cdn.glitch.global/5778ed75-793f-41e9-810d-b244bbed9dbd/inkogym.geojson?v=1657180982175")
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map);
  });
```

Is my json not correct or what is the issue?

Comment: Maybe add a `catch()` callback to see whether something is thrown.

Comment: And just check the console in devtools and everything becomes clear.